# ¿En Javascript cómo se debería reutilizar un valor de una variable, que utilizo dentro de una función, en otra función?

Tags: javascript, funciones, variables, function, variables-globales

Tengo una consulta y es acerca de cómo debería pasar el resultado de una función a otra función, es decir, reutilizar un valor de una variable, que utilizo dentro de una función, en otra función... por ejemplo:

```
function miFuncion(a, b ) {
   let resultado = a + b;
   return resultado;
}
```

y esta variable, resultado de esta función, se pueda utilizar en otra como:

```
function otraFuncion(resultado, c ) {
       let total = resultado + c;
       return total;
    }
```

Intuyo que se podría hacer con var pero quizás no sería lo más idóneo, pero al hacerlo con let, dicha variable saldrá de su alcance, de su scope y no podría ser llamada fuera de la función pues solo vive en ella... está mal el planteamiento hecho o mediante el return si me dispone la variable para reutilizarla globalmente... ¿quizás dependería del código y por ende de la lógica que me haya planteado a hacer?

Comment: El valor devuelto por la función `miFuncion` lo guardas en una variable y eso lo pasas como argumento a `otraFuncion`. Tratar de reutilizar el valor usando variables globales es un mal diseño.

Comment: Ok, entiendo @Lobos pero y si tengo distintas variables dentro de la función como por ejemplo:  
function miFuncion(a, b ) {
   let dato1 = a
   let dato2 = b
   let resultado = a + b;
   return resultado;
}
y quiero solo utilizar la variable dato1 en otra función, ¿se podría?

Comment: No se puede porque estaría fuera de su ámbito. De ser ese el caso en el que se necesita reutlizar el valor de una variable interna habría que analizar el diseño y plantearlo de otra forma. Recuerda que una función es una especie de contrato: el cliente sabe que puede pasarle parámetros y que se le devolverá un resultado. Lo que se usa de la función es el valor que retorna. No existe el caso de guardar valores internos de la función para compartir con otras funciones.

Comment: Y para qué quieres hacer eso? Si tienes un caso concreto en el que lo quieras usar ve al grano y plantealo. Siempre es mejor idea que las funciones sean independientes, que no tengan una referencia a algo de fuera de su ámbito. Que se valgan por sí mismas aunque pudiendo llamar a otras funciones dentro de ellas.

Comment: Me parece que es tan fácil como que no has entendido el concepto de `return`... puesto que lo que preguntas no tiene sentido si entiendes que puedes almacenar el resultado de tu función en una variable y luego hacer lo que quieras con ella, ya que además, ese resultado es un parámetro en tu siguiente función... es tan fácil como `let x = miFuncion(2,3); let y = otraFuncion(x, 5); console.log(y);`

Answer (score 1):

### Javascript Closures

Lo que pides no es del todo imposible. No veo un caso de uso para esto, no lo has presentado, pero para este tipo de cosas existen los [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) en javascript.

Un closure, es la capacidad de una función de referirse al ámbito externo (scope) de donde fue declarada.

Por ejemplo (con destructuring):

```
function suma(a,b) {
    const result = a+b;
    const innerFunction = (numeroExterno) =>{
        return numeroExterno + result;
}
    return  {
        result,
        innerFunction
    }
}

 const {result, innerFunction}= suma(4,5); // es la misma inner function y conoce de 'result';
 console.log('result', result); //9
 console.log('innerFunction',innerFunction(6)); // 15
```

Sin destructuring:

```
function suma(a,b){
    const result = a+b;
    return function innerFunction(numeroExterno){
        return numeroExterno + result;
    }    
}

const innerFunction= suma(4,5); // es la misma inner function y conoce de 'result';

console.log(innerFunction(6)); // 15
```

La función `suma(a,b)` suma ambos números y guarda el resultado en la constante `result`. Luego devuelve la función `innerFunction()` (es una función que devuelve una función), quien conoce el resultado aunque esté declarado en un scope externa a ella. La función `innerFunction()` toma el resultado declarado en la "función padre", y lo suma con el 6 que le pasamos.

Y de esta manera obtienes lo que buscas (kindof).

Te recomiendo el libro [You Don't Know JS](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS) disponible en github gratuitamente. Ahí aprendí eso. Cuándo se usa? No lo sé. Pero se puede.

Saludos

Edit: El fiddle por si lo necesitas
Edit2: le agrego destructuring para que tengas acceso a resultado y a la innerFunction :)

```js
function suma(a,b){
      const result = a+b;
      const innerFunction = (numeroExterno) =>{
        return numeroExterno + result;
    }
    return  {
      result,
      innerFunction
    }
}
 
const {result, innerFunction}= suma(4,5); // es la misma inner function y conoce de 'result';
console.log('result', result); //9
console.log('innerFunction',innerFunction(6)); // 15
```

Comment: Si pudieras regresar el primer ejemplo sin destructuring, saludos

Comment: Lo agregué... No veo cómo añade valor a la respuesta, pero si lo pides imagino es por algo

Answer (score 0):

Mira el siguiente ejemplo. Tenemos un número correlativo global. El sistema entra a un bucle de N iteraciones y en cada una va incrementando el correlativo.

```js
var globalNumber = 500

function bump() {
  ++globalNumber
}


for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  bump()
  console.log(`bucle ${i}, siguiente correlativo: ${globalNumber}`)
}
```

Muchas otras partes del programa usan ese correlativo así que tiene que ser un valor global, de modo que todos usen el mismo. ¿Verdad?
Pero un día un compañero de equipo (o tú mismo) estuvieron refactorizando y -como la función bump no estaba documentada- se aseguraron de incrementar el correlativo en el mismo bucle (poniendo `globalNumber++`).

```js
var globalNumber = 500

function bump() {
  ++globalNumber
}


for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  bump()
  console.log(`bucle ${i}, siguiente correlativo: ${globalNumber++}`)
}
```

Al poco tiempo alguien que necesita usar este valor, nota que los correlativos están avanzando de 2 en 2. Como no conoce bien el código y no quiere arriesgarse a romperlo, prefiere "rectificarlo" en cada uso. Esa rectificación por supuesto se convertirá en un bug cuando quiten el bug introducido en la refactorización...

Aunque es cómodo tener una referencia global de un cierto objeto (de partida para usarlo desde la consola), manejar el estado de una aplicación no es trivial. Debuggear dónde se está mutando una referencia puede ser una pesadilla.

**¿En qué casos sí tiene sentido manejar un estado global?**

Dan Abramov, autor de Flux, dice que las librerías de manejo de estado son como las gafas. Cuando te hagan falta te darás cuenta. Hasta entonces, no te hacen falta.