# Copiar parametros en javaScript

Tags: javascript

**Resumen**

Tengo una función que me retorna una variable, aqui un poco de contexto

```
  p = document.createElement("p");
  p.classList.add("replay");

  return p;
```

Esta variable la quiero usar como parámetro en otra función, alguien sabe como puedo copiar el contenido de esta varible ?

Comment: Te sirve [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/512257/en-javascript-c%c3%b3mo-se-deber%c3%ada-reutilizar-un-valor-de-una-variable-que-utilizo/512272#512272)?

Answer (score 0):

Si lo he entendido bien, tu función devuelve el valor de `p` y quieres usar dicho valor como argumento de otra función.

Supongamos que la función que delvuelve `p` es esta:

```
     function tu_funcion_que_devuelve_p()
{
     p = document.createElement("p");
     p.classList.add("replay");
     return(p)
}
```

Recogemos el valor de `p` en una variable:

```
var valorDevuelto=tu_funcion_que_devuelve_p();
```

Y luego usamos esa variable como argumento de la función que la necesite:

```
     funcion_que_usa_la_variable(valorDevuelto);
    
    
    function funcion_que_usa_la_variable(argumento)
    {
    console.log(argumento); //<-- argumento es igual a p
    }
```